# How to close MATLAB editor window/windows using command?

Tags: matlab

I want to know if there is any way to close the editor window (like function, script)using Matlab command.

Comment: This question is not detailed enough. Add more context about what you want to achieve and your environment. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Get the editor service

```
editor  = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLEditorServices; % main editor service
```

Step 2. Choose either of following depending on your requirement

```
editor.getEditorApplication.close; % Close editor windows (with prompt to save)
editor.getEditorApplication.closeNoPrompt; % Close editor windows
```